# How to add a class active in a three level of menu where href attribute has the same pass

Tags: jquery

I have three level of submenu created dynamically. I want to add class="active" where the text has the same url.

A space and comma will be replaced with under score.

For example, Glass, plast, gummi og porselen page will be

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/folder/Glass_plast_gummi_og_porselen.asp
```

Each href attribute has the same path as in URL

HTML

```
<ul id="submenu">
        <ul><li><a href="Grunnskole.asp" title="" class="">Grunnskole</a>


            <ul><li><a href="Forskerspiren.asp" title="" class="">Forskerspiren</a>


            <ul><li><a href="Sikkerhet.asp" title="" class="">Sikkerhet</a>


            </li><li><a href="Laboratorieutstyr(1).asp" title="" class="">Laboratorieutstyr</a>


            </li><li><a href="Glass_plast_gummi_og_porselen.asp" title="" class="">Glass, plast, gummi og porselen</a>


            </li><li><a href="Datalogging.asp" title="" class="">Datalogging</a>


            </li></ul></li><li><a href="Mangfold_in_naturen.asp" title="" class="">Mangfold in naturen</a>


            </li><li><a href="Kropp_og_helse.asp" title="" class="">Kropp og helse</a>


            </li><li><a href="Verdensrommet.asp" title="" class="">Verdensrommet</a>


            </li><li><a href="Fenomener_og_stoffer.asp" title="" class="">Fenomener og stoffer</a>


            </li></ul></li><li><a href="Sikkerhet_og_inventar(1).asp" title="" class="">Sikkerhet og inventar</a>


            </li><li><a href="Laboratorieutstyr.asp" title="" class="">Laboratorieutstyr</a>


            </li></ul>

    </ul>
```

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `window.location.pathname` to obtain just the filename, then use the attribute-ends-with or attribute-equals selectors:

```
// Get the current file name from window.location.pathname
var file = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();

// Look for <a> elements whose `href` matches the file 
$("#submenu a[href$='"+file+"']").addClass("active");
```

Using this method, you don't have the ambiguity that comes from 2 characters being replaced with an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

This works: http://www.jsfiddle.net/BBvLN/. The way you are cleaning up the URL is not correct. Also, you want to match the href of the a tag, not the text contained in the a tag.

```
var url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/folder/Glass_plast_gummi_og_porselen.asp";
var slug = url.replace('http://www.mywebsite.com/folder/','');

$("#submenu a[href=" + slug + "]").addClass("active");
```

Comment: @shin: The method to get the file name from Andy E (+1) is more elegant and more robust. The idea is the same concerning the jQuery code.